# Submit Flash AS2 form via AJAX

Tags: ajax, actionscript-2

I have a client who makes Flash AS2 based language learning software.

They wanted to add a bug report email to the apps.

It is dead simple if you don't mind the swf's post opening a new tab:

```
on (release, releaseOutside) {
  var my_Var:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
  my_Var.brsub = subject.text;
  my_Var.brmsg = message.text;
  my_Var.send("bug_report.php", "_blank", "POST");
}
```

I am looking for docs or an example in AS2 of making this post via AJAX and not opening the new tab.

Anyone know where I can read up on it.  I know it must be out there but my Googling has come up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make an AJAX Request in Flash to process that request:
you can use the `loadVariables` method to send data via POST, without leaving your Flash movie:

[Adobe Help Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001935.html)

Comment: Thank you!  Client ended up preferring HTML form after all that but will remember this for future.